# How to intercept and possibly cancel onSelect in React Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-observable

I am very new to React Bootstrap and exploring how much it is customizable. While it's easy to hook into `onSelect`, I can't find any way to cancel the action itself. For example, if user has unsaved changes and should not go to the other route, then how onSelect can be prevented?

This is from React Bootstrap docs with a little change:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

// import './Header.scss';

function myOnSelect(eventKey, event) {
    console.log(eventKey);
    console.log(event);
    alert(`Going ${eventKey}`);
    return false  // How to prevent from going there???
}

export const Header = props => {
    const {brand} = props.topNav;
    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="sm" bg="light" variant="light" sticky="top" 
            onSelect={myOnSelect}>
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">{brand}</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"/>
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
                    <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Divider/>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
                        Dank memes
                    </Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
};
```

Note: I do not mean going away to completely another page via a link, just another route inside the same page. It can be for "unsaved changes" or some other temporary reason, so disabling navbar menus is an overkill from UX point of view.

Extra twist to this is the project is going to use react-observable (with Redux and RxJS) for event/action logic, so it would be nice to understand how easy it is to hook React Boostrap into it. That is, some actions will need to be intercepted and handled in the epics and other middleware instead of following default React Bootstrap automation. So:

The example here can have some very specific solution, but could be **nice to also hear how easy it is to do action-interceptions in other places of React Bootstrap** or whether the javascript logic should be heavily customized or even abandoned.

I guess, for Navs the answer is somewhere in these arrangements: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/AbstractNavItem.js

Maybe explicitly set `activeKey` property together with `event.preventDefault();` can be used to build the desired control over nav.

Comment: Not sure but you can try cancelDefault on the event or try to add onClick on the elements that navigate and do a cancelDefault on that event.

Comment: Yes, `event.preventDefault();` worked. Does it mean, that I need to equip all react bootstrap components with overriden event triggers?

Comment: @HMR Actually, this does not work: Bootstrap still changes current nav item even though route does not change...

Answer (score 0):

We cannot stop the select from performing its onchange property. It will execute as soon as we select an option. Consider adding conditions in the myOnSelect function

```
    function myOnSelect(eventKey, event) {
       console.log(eventKey);
       console.log(event);

    if(condition) {
      //do something
      alert(`Going ${eventKey}`);
    }
    else {
     //do something else
     return false  // How to prevent from going there???
    }
   }
```

Comment: So how can I prevent going to eventKey and show a modal / stay on the same page and/or show a confirmation to the user, so the user can continue or cancel the action (of going to another page)? Is the answer I just can't do that? How to cancel transition? Is there a way to customize React Bootstrap componen(s) so transition is not unconditional?